# NSApplication sendEvent does not return while in live rezise

Tags: macos, opengl, resize, draw, polling

I have a polling main loop in c++ (opengl game), using code in objC for input and to handle mac specifics.
I want to continue doing drawing during a resize operation, but my polling stops in 'sendEvent' for a mouse left down message, and does not exit before the mouse is released and the resize finished, and no redraw is made.

[run once per main loop]

```
int FsPollDeviceC()
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   while(1)
   {
      [pool release];
      pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
      NSEvent *event;
      event = [NSApp
      nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask
      untilDate: [NSDate distantPast]
      inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
      dequeue:YES];
      if(event!=nil)
      {
         [NSApp sendEvent:event];
         [NSApp updateWindows];
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   [pool release];
   return windowclosed==0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Code https://sourceforge.net/p/galaxyv2/code/HEAD/tree/ext_include/mac/fsmacosxwrapper.m [row 1147]
Based on FsSimpleWindow (http://ysflight.in.coocan.jp/programming/fssimplewindow/e.html) but extended.

The entire project source is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/galaxyv2/files/galaxyv2/galaxyv2_1.81/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this with a redraw callback back to c-code on

```
@implementation YsOpenGLView
-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds
```

This function is called on each change in size during the resize (while the mouse button is pressed, and the normal polling operation is halted).

The entire code can be found in http://sourceforge.net/projects/galaxyv2/files/galaxyv2/galaxyv2_1.82/galaxyv2_1.82_src.zip/download

For the implementation:
    fsmacosxwrapper.m
    fsmacosxwrappercpp.cpp
    fssimplewindow.h

For the usage:
    galaxy.cpp@1202 and @1270